# need to init the JFrame

Tags: java, swing

I dont know how to init the JFrame windows. What I need to write to init im?

I have created at the main this:

```
Panel Panel=new Panel();

Panel.init();

JFrame frame = new JFrame("Shape Project");
frame.add(Panel);
frame.setResizable(false);
frame.setSize(new Dimension(1200, 650));
frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
frame.setVisible(true);
```

and in the JPanel class I have write this:

```
public  class Panel extends JFrame  
{   
    public void init()
    {
    }   
}
```

But when I active the frame it's does not active. What I need to write at the init func that the windows will open?

Comment: What do you mean by init the frame? also, why do you use the same name for variable and class (`Panel Panel = new Panel()`)?

Comment: i want to design there the windows so i init the frame in the class that called Panel

Answer (score 3):

Try `pack();` method of JFrame. If you are planning to develop with Swing, I recommend you to follow this tutorial:

http://download.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/index.html

Answer (score 1):

You already have a JFrame (frame). so now you should add components for your panel (you may do it in the main class as well). Such components are JTextField, JButton, etc. (and even another JPanel) each component you can add to the panel using `panel.add(component_name);` it is also recommended to follow the tutorial as **Erkan** mentioned.

Comment: but if i want to add them from the Panel class how can i do that?

Comment: When you are in the panel class, you can create each element, and add it as I wrote below, but instead of writing `panel.add(component)` use just `add(component)` or `this.add(component)` [since you're already in the object] for example:
`public void init() {
     JButton new_button = new JButton("Press");
     this.add(new_button);
     JTextArea new_text_area = new JTextArea("Text");
     add(new_text_area);
}`

Answer (score 1):

Your `panel` class should extend `JPanel`, not JFrame.
You can add components to `JPanel` such as `JButton, JList, etc`

This is an example code you need to init a JFrame if you don't create own classes:

```
public class LogMain 
{
    public static void main(String[] args)
    {   
        JFrame window = new JFrame("Log");
        window.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        window.setSize(300,300);
        window.setResizable(false);
        JPanel panel = new JPanel();
        JButton openFile = new JButton("Btn1");
        JButton openDir = new JButton("Btn2");
        panel.add(openFile);
        panel.add(openDir);
        window.add(panel);
        window.setLocationRelativeTo(null);
        window.setVisible(true);

     }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

this is my example about the init of JFrame :

```
public class Windows{

  public static void main(String args[]){

  SJFrame window = new SJFrame("NEWNEWNEW");
  window.init();

   }
}


public class SJFrame extends JFrame(){

  public SJFrame(String s){

  super(s);
  }
  void init(){

  Container panel = this.getContentPane();

  panel.setBackground(Color.green);
  panel.setLayout(new GridLayout(5,1));
  JLabel jl1 = new JLabel("UserName");
  JLabel jl2 = new JLabel("PassWord");

  this.add(jl1);
  this.add(jl2);
  this.setDefaultCloseOperation( JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE) ;
  this.setSize(300,100);
  this.pack();
  this.setVisible(true);
 }
}
```